# What is difference between Parent and NamingContainer in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

What is difference between these two statements? In particular, I'm interested in which one is more optimized.

```
GridViewRow currentItem = (GridViewRow)drp_Vendor.Parent;
```

and

```
GridViewRow currentItem = (GridViewRow)drp_Vendor.NamingContainer;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic difference is that `NamingContainer` will navigate up the control tree until it finds an ancestor that is a naming container (implements the [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) interface, while `Parent` will return the immediate parent in the control tree.

In your case, the GridViewRow appears to be both the immediate parent and the naming container of your drp_Vendor control.

But if, for example, you put your drp_Vendor control inside a `Panel` in a `TemplateField`, then the Parent will be the Panel while the NamingContainer will be the GridViewRow.

As for which is the "most optimized", the `Parent` property will be very slightly faster, but the difference will be insignificant.